# pymunk boxes on flat surfaces freak out

Tags: pymunk

I am having an issue with boxes that land on flat surfaces freaking out when they land, and changing their angle slightly. The following piece of code simulates a box with a flat bottom landing on a flat surface.

```py
import pymunk

space = pymunk.Space()
space.gravity = (0, -1)
box_body = pymunk.Body()
box_shape = pymunk.Poly.create_box(box_body, (1, 1))
box_body.position = (0, 20)
box_body.velocity = (0, 0)
box_shape.mass = 1
floor = pymunk.Segment(space.static_body, (-5, 0), (5, 0), 1)
space.add(floor, box_body, box_shape)
for _ in range(63):
    space.step(0.1)
print(box_body.angle)
```

I would expect the angle to be `0.0`, as there is nothing that should be causing it to rotate. However, I actually get a value of `-4.8183679268731794e-14`. If I change the 63 to 64, I get `7.805375706901558e-15`. It's fairly minor in this case, but when other dynamic objects interact with the box, it goes crazy and can often launch other objects at high speed. Why does this happen, and what can I do to prevent it? I've tried increasing the mass significantly, but the results don't change.

Comment: your link to github is leading to 404 page not found, make sure your project is public.

Comment: Just set it public.

Comment: Can you write what python and pymunk version you are using, and what OS you are on? I tried your example and got the expected 0 angle.

Comment: python 3.9.7 with pymunk 6.2.0 on Windows 10.

Comment: I have tried with a couple of different versions of Python (3.7, 3.8 and 3.9) on Win 10 all with the same result (the result is 0.0)

Comment: Do you use 32 or 64 bit python?

Comment: In my system settings, it says 64 bit. When I launch python, it says "Python 3.9.7 (tags/v3.9.7:1016ef3, Aug 30 2021, 20:19:38) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32".

Comment: Hmm. Maybe this would be more suited as a bug report on the pymunk github tracker at https://github.com/viblo/pymunk/issues. But one thing I thought about, can you try the box2d_pyramid.py and box2d_vertical_stack.py examples included in pymunk? https://github.com/viblo/pymunk/blob/master/examples/box2d_pyramid.py and https://github.com/viblo/pymunk/blob/master/examples/box2d_vertical_stack.py