Why do objects start spinning after colliding with a floor in Python Arcade/Pymunk?
Why do rectangular object without rotation start spinning after colliding with a flat wall in Python Arcade/Pymunk? How to solve this problem?
Let the rectangular object has angular velocity 0, angle 0, center of gravity (0,0) and moves straight. After which the rectangular object collides with a flat wall.
I noticed that rectangular objects begin to spin and shift after a collision with walls (static objects) in Arcade. Depending on the ratio of height and width, the turning speed is different. But it always present.

Since I use Python Arcade and Pymunk, I see the following possible solutions to the problem:

Set moment of object to INF. But then object never rotate so this is strange solution.
Get all calculations (related to the collision) from Chipmunk in hit_handler via _arbiter._arbiter: pymunk._chipmunk.ffi.CData. Somehow process the data from CData in Python and figure out how to fix the data that causes the error described above. It would be great if someone could tell me how to do this.
Perform calculations for velocity and angular_velocity from scratch in Python. But this method essentially doubles the number of calculations.

It would be great if someone tell another way.
Perhaps this is a bug in the Chipmunk2d library and there is no simple way. I've been struggling with this problem for a very long time. Thank you in advance for any help.
Arcade 2.6.17
Pymunk 6.4.0
Python 3.10.14
This is minimal reproducible example (without Arcade for minimum code):
import pyglet

import pymunk
import pymunk.pyglet_util
from pymunk import Vec2d


class Main(pyglet.window.Window):
    def __init__(self):

        pyglet.window.Window.__init__(self, vsync=False)

        pyglet.clock.schedule_interval(self.update, 1 / 60.0)
        self.fps_display = pyglet.window.FPSDisplay(self)

        self.create_world()

        self.draw_options = pymunk.pyglet_util.DrawOptions()
        self.draw_options.flags = self.draw_options.DRAW_SHAPES

    def create_world(self):
        self.space = pymunk.Space()
        self.space.gravity = Vec2d(0.0, -9.0)
        self.space.sleep_time_threshold = 0.3

        static_lines = [
            pymunk.Segment(self.space.static_body, Vec2d(20, 55), Vec2d(600, 55), 1),
            pymunk.Segment(self.space.static_body, Vec2d(550, 55), Vec2d(550, 400), 1),
        ]
        for l in static_lines:
            l.friction = 0.3
            l.elasticity = 1
        self.space.add(*static_lines)

        size = 20
        mass = 1.0
        moment = pymunk.moment_for_box(mass, (size//2, size))
        body = pymunk.Body(mass, moment)
        body.position = Vec2d(300 + 0 * 50, 105 + 5 * (size + 0.1))
        shape = pymunk.Poly.create_box(body, (size//2, size))
        shape.elasticity = 1
        shape.friction = 0.3
        self.space.add(body, shape)

    def update(self, dt):
        self.space.step(dt)

    def on_draw(self):
        self.clear()
        self.fps_display.draw()
        self.space.debug_draw(self.draw_options)


def main():
    main = Main()
    pyglet.app.run()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()


Please include the version of Python and arcade you are using, and reduce your code to an [mre] as much as possible.  358 lines is a bit much to wade through, especially with  all the extra print commands and handlers that do nothing but print.  If your example can include numpy to reduce the package install needs, as  you only use it on one line, even better.  Also, focus your question a bit more, if possible. Clarify exactly what you want the "correct" behavior to be. My assumption is you want the sprite to have no angular momentum change on impact, but not 100% clear.

Have you asked the devs: https://github.com/viblo/pymunk/issues? There you can find https://github.com/viblo/pymunk/issues/200 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69156894/pymunk-boxes-on-flat-surfaces-freak-out. I assume, https://stackoverflow.com/users/412772/viblo is the owner of Pymunk

I didn't ask devs. I will try it.

My solution - change velocity by bounce from arbiter:CData and change angular velocity in special case. So we have next steps:

Setting up FFI (use this file )


self.ffibuilder = FFI()
with open(r"Path\chipmunk_cdef.h", "r") as f:
    self.ffibuilder.cdef(f.read())



Add pre_handler to remember angular velocity


def pre_handler(_arbiter, _space, _data):
    _data["a_w"] = _arbiter.shapes[0].body.angular_velocity
    return True



Add post_handler to change velocity in case (prev. angular velocity small and contact points have similar distances)


def post_handler(ffibuilder, _arbiter, _space, _data):
    arb = ffibuilder.cast("struct cpArbiter *",_arbiter._arbiter)
    n = (arb.n.x, arb.n.y)
    distances = [i.distance for i in _arbiter.contact_point_set.points]
    if distances.count(distances[0]) == len(distances) and abs(_data["a_w"])<=0.1**15:
        _arbiter.shapes[0].body.velocity = cpvmult(n,abs(arb.contacts[0].bounce))
        _arbiter.shapes[0].body.angular_velocity = 0.0


Collision slop and bias also affect. We can set self.space.collision_slop = N (N max number what you can use, N=2 for me) or set some custom calculations in arb (post_handler).
For Python Arcade answer is the same.
Full code:

import pyglet

import pymunk
import pymunk.pyglet_util
from pymunk import Vec2d
from cffi import FFI

def pre_handler(_arbiter, _space, _data):
    _data["a_w"] = _arbiter.shapes[0].body.angular_velocity
    return True

def post_handler(ffibuilder, _arbiter, _space, _data):
    arb = ffibuilder.cast("struct cpArbiter *",_arbiter._arbiter)
    n = (arb.n.x, arb.n.y)
    distances = [i.distance for i in _arbiter.contact_point_set.points]
    if distances.count(distances[0]) == len(distances) and abs(_data["a_w"])<=0.1**15:
        _arbiter.shapes[0].body.velocity = cpvmult(n,abs(arb.contacts[0].bounce))
        _arbiter.shapes[0].body.angular_velocity = 0.0
            
def cpvmult(t1,number):
    return t1[0]*number,t1[1]*number

class Main(pyglet.window.Window):
    def __init__(self):

        pyglet.window.Window.__init__(self, vsync=False)

        pyglet.clock.schedule_interval(self.update, 1 / 60.0)
        self.fps_display = pyglet.window.FPSDisplay(self)

        self.create_world()

        self.draw_options = pymunk.pyglet_util.DrawOptions()
        self.draw_options.flags = self.draw_options.DRAW_SHAPES
        
        self.ffibuilder = FFI()
        with open(r"C:\Users\HYPERPC\Downloads\chipmunk_cdef.h", "r") as f:
            self.ffibuilder.cdef(f.read())

    def add_handler(self, shape, pre_handler=None,post_handler=None):

        def _f1(arbiter, space, data):
            post_handler(self.ffibuilder, arbiter, space, data)

        def _f2(arbiter, space, data):
            return pre_handler(arbiter, space, data)

        h = self.space.add_wildcard_collision_handler(shape.collision_type)
        if post_handler:
            h.post_solve = _f1
        if pre_handler:
            h.pre_solve = _f2
    
    def create_world(self):
        self.space = pymunk.Space()
        self.space.gravity = Vec2d(0.0, -9.0)
        self.space.sleep_time_threshold = 0.3
        self.space.collision_slop = 2
        static_lines = [
            pymunk.Segment(self.space.static_body, Vec2d(20, 55), Vec2d(600, 55), 1),
            pymunk.Segment(self.space.static_body, Vec2d(550, 55), Vec2d(550, 400), 1),
        ]
        for l in static_lines:
            l.friction = 0.3
            l.elasticity = 1
        self.space.add(*static_lines)

        size = 20
        mass = 1.0
        moment = pymunk.moment_for_box(mass, (size//2, size))
        body = pymunk.Body(mass, moment)
        body.position = Vec2d(300 + 0 * 50, 105 + 5 * (size + 0.1))
        shape = pymunk.Poly.create_box(body, (size//2, size))
        shape.elasticity = 1
        shape.friction = 0.3
        self.space.add(body, shape)
        
        self.add_handler(shape, pre_handler = pre_handler)
        self.add_handler(shape, post_handler = post_handler)

    def update(self, dt):
        self.space.step(dt)

    def on_draw(self):
        self.clear()
        self.fps_display.draw()
        self.space.debug_draw(self.draw_options)


def main():
    main = Main()
    pyglet.app.run()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()


